# wake up, awaken and awake

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs, morphology

> He **woke up** to find others gone.

> He **awakened** to find others gone.

> He **awoke** to find others gone.

All of the sentences can be found grammatical in OED and they seem identical in meaning.
I am wondering whether they have particular connotations.

Comment: They all mean the same, but _woke up_ would be the most natural in everyday speech, and _awakened_ sounds rather high-flown and literary.